# onload event in home page

Tags: javascript, css

I have some text in a div in my home page, I want this should appear with light background (in less opacity) and the width of the div should be 50%, and will load after 2seconds after the page load. I tried with javascript but its not working. 
in my css file  "transition: width 2s;"

```
var slider = document.getElementById("splasher");

function splasher(){
slider.style.width="50%";
}
```

I put onload in the div which is

```
onload ="splasher();"
```

any help for this

Comment: You need to make sure you don't run the `var slider=...` line before the element is loaded.

Comment: The `onload` will need to go on the `body` probably.. not on the `div`.

Comment: thanks Scott, it runs after the element is loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like the following. Initially we wait the DOM to be loaded. Then we set a timeout for the splasher.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    var slider = document.getElementById("splasher");
  
    function splasher(){
        slider.style.width="50%";
        slider.style.opacity = 0.5;
        slider.style.display = 'block';
    }
  
    setTimeout(splasher, 2000);
})
```

```html
<h4>Slider Demo</h4>
<div id="splasher" style="display:none;">Slider</div>
```

Comment: thanks Chris, but this ("Slider" text) should show after 2seconds of page load & the background should be less visible

Comment: The answer @Christos gave you will work just fine. Based on your description, you want the delay after the page is rendered, not when it's loaded. Thus, change `"DOMContentLoaded"` to `"load"`. Everything else you describe can be accomplished with CSS.

Comment: You are welcome ! Not having knowledge of your html code it's a bit difficult to guide you. However, please check my update I think that it's close to what you are looking for.

Comment: @Christos (off topic) I tried to upload my local site to webserver. I was using XAMPP, now I tried with godaddy but it shows error. "Could not connect: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)" any solution for this

Comment: It seems that you have an authentication issue. Verify that you use the correct credentials. If you are sure that you use the correct credentials, then you should contact the administrator(s) of the webserver and let him know about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your slider might not have been rendered yet. Put in inside `onload` as well.

```
<body onload="loaded()">

function loaded() {
 var slider = document.getElementById("splasher");

 function splasher(){
   slider.style.width="50%";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you don't run the `var slider=...` line before the element is loaded.